# Oracle not evaluating nvl as expected

Tags: oracle, nvl

This query returns rows where colA is null:

```
select * from viewA where colA is null;
```

But this query does not -

```
select * from viewA where nvl(colA, 'X') = 'X';
```

Any idea why the second query is not returning any results?

Comment: What datatype is colA?

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that  `'X'` == `'X'`, i.e. have you used another character that looks like an X and what is the datatype of `cola`? NCHAR for instance?

Comment: I just tried your test on a table column that has some null values, and checked the count where `IS NULL` and also where `nvl(colA, 'X') = 'X'`, and I got the same result. Something else is affecting your result set.

Comment: could it be connected to the fact this is view as opposed to a table?

Comment: @Marcus Shouldn't make any difference. What is the output of select 
  colA, 
  dump(colA),
  dump(nvl(colA, 'X')),
  dump('X') 
from viewA where colA is null;

Comment: No it won't make a difference, what you're saying is happening is probably impossible... it'd be interesting to see if you can replicate this anywhere and then provide code that others can use to test it.

Comment: Please include some sample data. Ideally a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87690/1

Comment: I'm not sure I'd dismiss the view as a factor so quickly, there have seem been some bugs in this area. What version are you using, does adding a `no_push_pred` hint make any difference, and can you show the view code? Or ideally recreate the problem with a similarly-structured view that doesn't rely on your own tables. Or it might not be the view of course, but I don't have any other ideas *8-)

Answer (score -3):

select * from viewA where nvl(colA, 'null') = 'null';